# Error: Cannot find module 'Cloudinary' MERN stacke

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

In case of work, the project works completely and there are no problems. I try to upload it to a free server to make sure that everything is correct and works correctly, but it does not work and gives me an error.

I repeated the steps and made sure that I had downloaded all the required repositories, including Cloudinary, but the problem still persists. I used the https://www.cyclic.sh/ site, but an error appears. Then I used the render site, but the exact same error appears, but as I mentioned, it is localhost is working normally[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMPle.png)

Comment: Hi,, using images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you